# Using an iOS app for more than 7 days without a paid developer account?

Tags: ios

I want to put an app I wrote on my phone and use it long term. I don't have a paid developer account so right now it expires after 7 days. Is there any way I can use my app without paying $100/year for a professional developer account (without jailbreaking)? Seems kind of ridiculous that I'd have to pay to use my own app on my own phone.

Comment: You need to rebuild and reinstall the app from Xcode each week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you could see below, you **need to pay for developer program** to continue using your app in your device or as the comment suggests you can rebuild and sideload again and again but you'll lose all the data of your app.
[image]
Image Source: https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/