# How to export ios app file made in flutter and android studio?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, apk

I just started exploring flutter/dart ios, I still don't have Mac or iPhone, I want to test the platform to see is it for me. So I installed Mac(Mojave) in a virtual machine, Xcode, android studio, flutter ext,ext.. and my test app working fine on emulators (both android and ios).

My question is how to export an ios app file? I run "flutter build ios --debug" for example and get some errors like (your team has no devices from which to generate a provisioning profile...), do I need paid developer account or I can do this like with APK files (flutter build APK works just fine)...

Comment: Related: [Using an iOS app for more than 7 days without a paid developer account?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54248071/295004)

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround on creating an unsigned .ipa file for iOS without an Apple Developer account. You need the Flutter app to be run first on an iOS simulator - this will generate an iOS build located on `/build/ios.` Create a folder anywhere you like with the name Payload - note that this is case sensitive. Then navigate to `/build/ios/iphonesimulator` and copy-paste Runner.app to the `Payload` folder you've created. Compress the `Payload` folder with the default .zip format and rename **Payload.zip** to **Payload.ipa**