# Watchos app is uninstall automatically after some days

Tags: swift, watchos

Right now I don't have a developer account, so I used to install a watch app on Apple watch series 3 using Xcode. In the last few months, I observed that my app is usually uninstalled automatically after some days about one week even I run the app daily.

May I know what is it causes? What's the approach to find out it causes? Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you don't have a paid developer account.  A paid developer account will allow an app to remain for longer.  Currently 90 days when signed/deployed through Test Flight.

Comment: Thanks, CodeChimp for the response. Can you plz share the link which mentioned that non-paid developer will not allow an app for a long time?

Comment: Can't find anything on Apple giving explicit dates but here's a similar question. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54248071/using-an-ios-app-for-more-than-7-days-without-a-paid-developer-account